# Environment variables when run with 'sudo'

Tags: command-line, sudo, environment-variables

As example to my question, my `~/.bashrc` file contains this lines:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/ia32:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_PRELOAD=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so
```

so that Numpy (Python) could find libraries that it needs to run, as it's build with MKL and Intel compilers. This workflow isn't the best, but that's another story.

My question is **how can I pass arbitrary variables (like those in `~/.bashrc`) when I run program with 'sudo' (but not root)?**

Currently, if I run:

```
sudo python -c "import numpy"
```

I get an error:

```
ImportError: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*
```

Some suggestions as `sudo -i` or `sudo -E` does not change anything here.

---

**Edit:**

I can't answer my question (not enough points :D ) but I'll comment here, in a hope that there are other Linux newbies wondering about `sudo` traps.

[Only temporarily!] This works for me (`~/.bashrc`):

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH VAR1=SOME_VALUE VAR2=SOME_VALUE...'
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Environment variables can be simply passed after `sudo` in form ENV=VALUE and thay'll be accepted by followed command. It's not known to me if there are restrictions to this usage, so my example problem can be solved with:

```
sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/ia32:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_PRELOAD=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so python -c "import numpy"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080866/ssh-environment-variable-for-sudo-access

Comment: Still today this worked for me, on my Raspbian Jessy for my RPi 3 ... after almost a week breaking my head *why* didn't my script ran on startup. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Extremely useful, this works to populate a variable inside Docker Container as well where I require sudo.

Answer (score 33):

The `-E` option you mention seems to work just fine:

```
enzotib@host:~$ export DUMMY=dummy
enzotib@host:~$ sudo -E sh -c 'echo $DUMMY'
dummy
enzotib@host:~$ sudo -E env | grep DUMMY
DUMMY=dummy
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your answer. Can you provide example on scenario I posted above? i.e. to be able to run `sudo python -c "import numpy"` with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_PRELOAD` defined as written above?

Comment: @zetah: ok, i'm wrong, because it works for generic variable, but not for dymanic linking controlling variables, as stated in section `SECURITY NOTES` of `sudo` manual page.

Comment: It is simpler then that (as in provided answer), although `man sudo` does not make it clear, and when user tries to follow references pointed there, it is very easy to be discouraged by all branches needed to be followed, to be able to decrypt supposed meaning.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `-E` sudo option to preserve current environment (if you have rights to do that)

```
$ man sudo
 -E, --preserve-env
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve
             their existing environment variables.  The security policy may
             return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve
             the environment.
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to edit your `sudoers` by `sudo visudo` as possibly you've security policy plugin enabled which overrides your `PATH` by `secure_path` option. So add the path to the list and you can also use `env_keep` instead, for example:

```
Defaults env_reset
Defaults env_keep += "PATH PYTHONPATH"
```

To check if your `PATH` is overridden, run the following command:

```
$ sudo sudo -V | grep PATH
Value to override user's $PATH with: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

See also: [Why are PATH variables different when running via sudo and su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8646/21471) at Unix SE

Comment: +1, but `env_keep` does not work on PATH (in the sense that `sudo` still uses `secure_path` when looking for the command)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (`~/.bashrc`):

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH VAR1=SOME_VALUE VAR2=SOME_VALUE...'
```

<sup>Source: As per [OP edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/57915/2)</sup>

Comment: this works, but it is a bad idea because it makes running `sudo` less safe