# Added folders to PATH cannot be found using sudo

Tags: sudo, paths, environment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Environment variables when run with 'sudo'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo)

I've added a new folder to my path, but when running the programs (in that folder) with "sudo" it does not work.

When I type

```
sudo <command-name>
```

it returns:

```
sudo: <command-name>: command not found
```

How do I make it available for sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PATH is located in your ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, or ~/.bash_profile file.
This file is made for your account only.

When you set your PATH, you probably editted /home/yourname/.profile right?
Sudo doesnt (as one might think) uses the PATH from /root/.profile instead of /home/yourname/, nor does it always use your own PATH.

The problem is that a couple of variables are overwritten by sudo. Which ones depends on your system. As root, run:

```
sudo -V
```

It will tell you if your PATH is used or not.
You could then use sudo -E option to overwrite the using of the default PATH. See the description in the manpage about the /etc/sudoers file.

Comment: Can you please add that as an answer to the link I gave so your answer does not get lost if this question is closed.

Comment: it returns something that includes the line : Value to override user's $PATH with: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin

Answer (score 2):

That's strange.
Anyway I think that

```
sudo /FULL_PATH/program_name
```

will work.

Another good idea will be to add a symbolic link to it in the /sbin/ directory with

```
sudo ln -s /FULL_PATH/program_name /sbin
```

Comment: is there any way to change the PATH used in sudo ?