# how do you make the scripts in /home/$user/bin accessible using sudo?

Tags: bash, sudo

How do you make the scripts in /home/$user/bin accessible using sudo? as in:

```
sudo $NameOfScript
```

in using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: and http://askubuntu.com/questions/110028/added-folders-to-path-cannot-be-found-using-sudo

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I don't think this is a duplicate. I think that the OP want to know how to run that script with administrative privileges instead of user privileges.

Comment: yes i want to know how to make it is it requires sudo

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are reset for `sudo` for security reasons, including the `PATH` variable that controls which programs you can run conveniently at a prompt.

However, you can bypass this limitation by specifying the absolute or relative path to the command you want to use. In your example:

```
sudo /home/$user/bin/$NameOfScript
```

As compared to the approach of changing `PATH`, this preserves the security precautions around root's environment variables while still allowing you to run whatever program you want with `sudo`.