# arm linux gcc compiling.. exported path in .bashrc doesn't work with sudo but it works with su

Tags: bashrc

I'm a 1 week long linux user.

I've added

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin
```

to `.bashrc` for friendlyarm project and it works nice. The `arm-linux-gcc -v` command shows me details.

When I use `make modules` command in linux-2.6.38 source folder to compile, gives "permission denied" errors. So I use `sudo make modules` but it doesn't recognize `arm-linux-gcc` it says:

```
make: arm-linux-gcc: Command not found
```

So I have to use `su` and just use `make modules` as root, everything works.

Why doesn't it recognize the path that I've added to .bashrc when I use sudo? Is it normal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Environment variables when run with 'sudo'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo -E` instead of `sudo` to preserve your modified `PATH`. Otherwise `PATH` isn't preserved and thus `arm-linux-gcc` can't be found (see `man sudo` for details and possible permanent fixes).

If that doesn't work try `sudo env PATH=/path/to/gcc:$PATH make target`.

Comment: Still nothing.. same error "sudo -E make modules" results "make: arm-linux-gcc: Command not found"

Comment: @SerhatTürkman Does `sudo PATH="$PATH:/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin" make modules` also fail to find `arm-linux-gcc`? If so, I recommend adding this information to your question (by editing it), so it doesn't get wrongly closed as a duplicate of [that other question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo).