# Executable runs without sudo but not with sudo

Tags: sudo, php, environment-variables, xampp

I installed xampp in my system in the location `/opt/lampp`. After that I added the php location to my path variable using

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
```

So when I run `php -v` using terminal I get the expected output.

```
PHP 5.6.8 (cli) (built: Apr 20 2015 18:37:47) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

But when I run `sudo php -v` I get this:

```
sudo: php: command not found
```

I don't know why this happens. Am I doing something wrong while adding it to path variable?

**Edit:**

This question is not a duplicate of [Environment variables when run with 'sudo'](https://askubuntu.com/q/57915/356083), because in that question zetah asked how to pass arbitrary variables to a python command. They are able to execute `python` using `sudo`, but I can't execute `php` using `sudo`.

Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/57938/356083), I added the PATH to `sudo` using the following command:

```
sudo PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin php -v
```

but I am getting the output as before:

```
sudo: php: command not found
```

Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/57932/356083), I added `-E` to `sudo`, but I get the same result:

```
$ sudo -E php -v
sudo: php: command not found
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Environment variables when run with 'sudo'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo)

Comment: why would you need to run php as root?

Comment: Add the output of `$ which php`.

Comment: @prakharsing95 /opt/lampp/bin/php

Comment: @ElefantPhace I tried to install pear. In one documentation they mentioned to download the go-pear.phar and then run using `sudo php go-pear.phar`. So when i tried that i got this error. But when i try without `sudo` its worked. So I thought to ask question why php is not working with `sudo`.

Comment: What is `PATH` but an environment variable?

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? It sounds legit and well explained

Comment: @kos because I don't see any value in repeated questions asking for using environment variables with `sudo`, especially when OP refuses to understand.

Comment: @muru For coincidence, I've added this as an example of what I was talking about here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14192/please-stop-downvoting-easy-questions-if-you-are-doing-so

Comment: @kos my downvote came *after* OP's latest edit, so again, your example is flawed.

Comment: @muru Ah, I see. Well, got to remove it again I guess.

Comment: @muru As i said in the edit "in reference question  he can able to execute python using sudo and he is getting error when he uses arbitrary variable". But here i cant able execute php itself. And also i tried that answers also. Still no luck. If am done anything wrong in the edit means correct me.

Comment: @Mahendran What did you try? I don't see how your edit makes any difference. `PATH` is even explicitly mentioned in the the dupe's post.

Comment: @muru I updated the edit. Thanks for corrected me.

Comment: OK, try.. `sudo env PATH="$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin" php -v`.

Comment: thanks @muru. It's working perfectly. Once you add it as answer i ll accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make \`sudo\` follow my path via CLI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012922/can-i-make-sudo-follow-my-path-via-cli) Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/128413/setting-the-path-so-it-applies-to-all-users-including-root-sudo

Comment: I don't think this is actually a duplicate of either of those, because none of the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo) solve this problem except setting an alias, which decreases security, and exempting the user or using `exempt_group` in `sudoers` is overkill for just running a program as root (and... decreases security!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Why `sudo` doesn't use your PATH

The reason `sudo` ignores your PATH variable is that it has its own `secure_path`, and it's fairly determined to use it.

If you `sudo cat /etc/sudoers` or just `sudo grep secure /etc/sudoers`, you'll see what this path is on your system. I have this line:

```
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

The purpose of `sudo`'s `secure_path` is to try to make it less likely that a user with `sudo` privilege will (accidentally) run dangerous code as root after their path has been modified, perhaps to include local directories.

It's possible to avoid `sudo` using the `secure_path` altogether by modifying `/etc/sudoers` to comment out that line, but that would be a bad idea because it removes a security measure, and it's also unnecessary because you can easily work around it in various preferable ways.

### Getting `sudo` to use your PATH

To override the `secure_path` and make `sudo` use your PATH as currently defined, [as muru commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653029/executable-running-without-sudo-but-not-with-sudo#comment938601_653029), you can use:

```bash
sudo env PATH="$PATH" command
```

Note that the `-E` flag or merely assigning the variable do not work (on Ubuntu at least).

```bash
$ mkdir junk                            # create a test directory to add to PATH
$ echo "echo foo" > junk/useless        # create a harmless program
$ chmod u+x junk/useless                # make it executable
$ PATH="$PATH":~/junk                   # add directory to PATH
```

When adding to PATH, use the absolute path (the shell will expand `~` before assigning the variable). I don't need to `export` (and doing so does not help), because PATH is already exported, and changing its value will cause child processes to inherit the change too.

```bash
$ useless
foo
$ sudo useless
sudo: useless: command not found
$ sudo -E useless
sudo: useless: command not found
```

It's often expected that this will work... [`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/sudo.8.html) says:

```bash
-E, --preserve-env
            Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to
            preserve their existing environment variables.
```

But that doesn't work. The `-E` flag has no effect on `secure_path`, [which is possibly a bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91556/165104).

```bash
$ sudo PATH="$PATH" useless
sudo: useless: command not found
```

This does not affect `sudo`'s own environment, which has been set according to the security policy, configured by [`/etc/sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html). This includes `env_reset` and `secure_path` as defaults on Ubuntu, causing a minimal environment to be loaded and the PATH to be set to whatever is in `secure_path`.

If `sudo` were able to find a command called `useless` in one of its own path directories and run it, it would pass `PATH=$PATH` into its environment [as demonstrated here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43950957#43950957). But it will not itself use the given value of PATH. The solution is to run:

```bash
$ sudo env PATH="$PATH" useless
foo
```

This workaround uses the `env` command to set PATH. Unlike `sudo`, `env` uses the given variables to set the environment, then looks for the command argument and runs the command with the modified environment. As [`info (coreutils) env invocation`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#env-invocation) says:

> Modifications to `PATH` take effect prior to searching for *command*.

### Setting the PATH

When you changed your PATH variable to include the directory `/opt/lampp/bin`, you used this command:

```bash
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
```

This would be effective for the current shell and all the current shell's child processes, such as shells called from this shell. When you've exited this shell and all its children have exited, that modified PATH variable has been thoroughly forgotten, and when you open a new shell you will find the old PATH variable that does not include `/opt/lampp/bin`. For that reason, the full command [suggested by muru](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653029/executable-runs-without-sudo-but-not-with-sudo/1024004#comment938601_653029),

```bash
sudo env PATH="$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin" php -v
```

would have been necessary if you were not still using a shell where you had already added `/opt/lampp/bin`.

To change the path permanently, you would need to edit some configuration file that modifies your user environment or is read by shells when they start up. You can add a line to assign environment variables in your `~/.profile`, for example:

```bash
PATH="$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin"
```

Then, after logging out and back in (or running `source ~/.profile` to see the effect immediately), you would always be able to run

```bash
php -v
```

or

```bash
sudo env PATH="$PATH" php -v
```

without adjusting your PATH first.

### Less cumbersome alternatives

A more convenient workaround could be to make a symlink to the executable in a location that is in the `secure_path` and the default PATH, for example:

```bash
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php
```

You will then not need to do anything special when calling the command with `sudo`, nor will you ever need to take any steps to adjust your PATH, permanently or temporarily.

If the program you are installing has a name that is the same as the name of another program that system processes may attempt to call, then *give the symlink a different name*, to avoid confusing those processes. You can check that the name you want to use is not already the name of some other command using the `type` command:

```bash
$ type php
bash: type: php: not found
```

So on this system I can create a command `php` without fear of anything going wrong, at the moment. If I install other programs that provide a `php` command in future, I might have to re-think my configuration.

You could also make an alias for the command and add it to your `~/.bashrc`, for example:

```bash
alias sudo-php='sudo env PATH="$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin/php"'
```

You could then (after running `source .bashrc` or opening a new shell) run

```bash
sudo-php
```

instead of `sudo php` to run this program as root, and `sudo` will not claim to be ignorant of its location.

This alias would only be available in interactive shells, so it wouldn't confuse other programs.

Of course, it's possible to make an alias for just `sudo` to make it always use your PATH, with `alias sudo='sudo env PATH="$PATH"'`, but that's a bad idea as it would make the system less secure.