# Can I make `sudo` follow my path via CLI?

Tags: command-line, sudo, paths

You can edit `sudoers` file and set `secure_path` to match your path. This is documented in [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/why-are-path-variables-different-when-running-via-sudo-and-su).

Is there a command line switch I can pass to `sudo` such that it uses the path I have set? For example:

```
rick@alien:~$ sudo echo $PATH
/home/rick/bin:/home/rick/.local/bin:/mnt/e/bin:/mnt/e/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ echo $PATH
/home/rick/bin:/home/rick/.local/bin:/mnt/e/bin:/mnt/e/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ sudo which auto-brightness-config
/usr/local/bin/auto-brightness-config
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ which auto-brightness-config
/mnt/e/usr/local/bin/auto-brightness-config
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ sudo locate auto-brightness-config
/Desktop/Link to auto-brightness-config
/home/rick/Pictures/display-auto-brightness-config 1.png
/mnt/e/Desktop/Link to auto-brightness-config
/mnt/e/usr/local/bin/.auto-brightness-config
/mnt/e/usr/local/bin/Link to auto-brightness-config
/mnt/e/usr/local/bin/auto-brightness-config
/usr/local/bin/.auto-brightness-config
/usr/local/bin/Link to auto-brightness-config
/usr/local/bin/auto-brightness-config
```

When I run using `sudo` it is finding the wrong copy of the script in `/usr/local/bin` when I really want the version in `/mnt/e/usr/local/bin` .

If I don't want to maintain the path in `sudoers` file, is there a switch I can pass to `sudo` to use my path to find the right command?

Comment: `echo $PATH` and `sudo echo $PATH` are going to give you the same results because Bash expands the variable before running the commands. Instead of `sudo echo $PATH`, use `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'`.

Comment: I assume you know this, but you can specify the full command path on the command line: `sudo /mnt/e/usr/local/bin/auto-brightness-config`

Comment: @wjandrea Yes I know about hard-coding path. I just find it bizarre I can't find an easy way for `sudo` to use the user's path. I tried `-i` and `-h` switches to no avail. Still your point is well-taken. Thanks.

Comment: Personally I would move the binary to root's path or set root's path

Comment: @Panther but what I don't understand the binary is in `sudo $PATH` hierarchical order above, it just doesn't find it with as confirmed by `which`. I'm the only user on this laptop (I hope no one uses it when I'm working) so every time I set my path I don't want to remember to change it in `/etc/sudoers` as well.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It's probably not actually in the secure path. See my first comment.

Comment: @wjandrea Definitely not in `secure_path` which is default install including useless `/snap/bin` and missing important `/home/Me/bin`. The default install is: `secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu by default already has `secure_path` set:

```
~ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for muru on muru-1604:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin    
User muru may run the following commands on muru-1604:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

There is no command-line option that can override `secure_path` set in `sudoers`.

From [`man sudoers`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/sudoers.5.html):

```
 secure_path   Path used for every command run from sudo.  If you don't
               trust the people running sudo to have a sane PATH
               environment variable you may want to use this.  Another use
               is if you want to have the “root path” be separate from the
               “user path”.  Users in the group specified by the
               exempt_group option are not affected by secure_path.  This
               option is not set by default.
```

So either set `exempt_group` in `sudoers` and add yourself to that group, or exempt yourself from `sudoers`:

```
Defaults:rick !secure_path
```

(`rick` presumably being your username.)

Comment: I think most users will not want to use `exempt_group` for this, since users in exempt groups are also never required to enter their passwords to run commands with `sudo`. Although I don't think it's unreasonable to mention that `exempt_group` is a possible approach here, I recommend stating that explicitly, and I would recommend most people not do it unless they also want (and have thought through the implications of) that effect.