# What should /etc/sudoers contain normally?

Tags: visudo

When I run sudo visudo , what should it contain?
Please give me an example of what it should have normally for a sudo user.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files) or [How to modify an invalid '/etc/sudoers' file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file)

Comment: I think this is an example of a good question that is still off-topic as too broad because every installation could have a different definition of "normal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I change on new installations:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset, timestamp_timeout=120, pwfeedback
#Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
Defaults:rick !secure_path

  (... SNIP rest of file unchanged ...)
```

I put my changes at the top of the file. They are displayed in bold above:

- `timeout` makes sudo privalege last for 2 hours so I don't have retype password every 5 minutes or whatever the default is.
- `pwfeedback` places a `*` on screen with each key press during password input.
- `mail_badpass` stops an email being sent to my account each time I enter the sudo password incorrectly.
- `!secure_path` is explained here: [Can I make `sudo` follow my path via CLI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012922/can-i-make-sudo-follow-my-path-via-cli)