# Software installed under /opt folder not found when run as root or sudo

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, nodejs

I've installed some of the software under /opt folder by compiling. I've added their "bin" directory to the path inside "/etc/environment". I can also use them as a regular user. For eg: NodeJS 10.15.1 has been installed in /opt and giving 
`node -v` outputs `v10.15.1`.

Similarly if I run the same with sudo,

```
sudo node -v
```

I'm getting `sudo: node: command not found`.
If I become root by `sudo -s` and then execue `node -v`, I'm getting

```
Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install nodejs
```

The reason I want to use "sudo" is, I've installed "[Angular](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0)" using "npm". And at certain times, `ng serve` not reflecting new code changes automatically (which is default behavior of "ng serve" command).

So as pointed out in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092880/ng-serve-not-detecting-file-changes-automatically), I want to run this command with "sudo".

Why can't sudo find the executable when it has been added to "PATH"?

Comment: Did you add it to the root users PATH as well as you local user? What happens if you run it with sudo but specify the full path I.e. `sudo /opt/path/to/node` ?

Comment: @rohtua, running with fully qualified path will execute the program whether it's with "sudo" or not.

Comment: Try editing the root users .bashrc file in their home directory and adding the following to the end of the file, `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/path/to/node` that's the way I add applications or scripts to my path if they're installed in a custom location. You can do the same for local user as well. You'll have to close the running terminal session and start a new one for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Doesn't `sudo` reset the path to safe values ? Try to run `sudo echo $PATH`

Comment: @SorenA you'd need something more like `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'` (so that `$PATH` doesn't get expanded by the local shell). However `sudo` searches its own `secure_path` rather than root's `PATH` AFAIK

Comment: @SorenA, executing "sudo echo $PATH" showed contents of "/etc/environment" file as told by steeldriver.

Comment: @steeldriver, how to make either "sudo" command or "root" user to consider all the paths mentioned inside "/etc/environment" file?

Comment: @rohtua, I added node location to .bashrc file. It started executing after I changed to root user completely by "sudo -s", however, got some exception (**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Exited with code 3
    at ChildProcess.cp.once.code**). But just prepending "sudo" command ("`sudo /opt/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64/bin/ng serve --open`"), still showing "**/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory**". But one thing I don't understand is why paths in "/etc/environment" file is ignored? Why should I do these extra steps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executable runs without sudo but not with sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653029/executable-runs-without-sudo-but-not-with-sudo)