# sudoers file: allow sudo group execution of only certain binaries

Tags: sudo

I'm trying to restrict the sudo group on my Ubuntu 19.10 install to only a certain assortment ouf executables.

The sudoers file now has the following form:

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
#%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt,/usr/bin/apt-key,/usr/bin/apt-add-repository,/usr/bin/make

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Sadly the programs can still not be executed with the error message e.g. for `apt update`:

```
Sorry, user ubuntuuser is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/env PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin apt update' as root on Ubuntumachine.
```

If I add `/usr/bin/env` to the executable list I can again execute **every** and **not only** the restricted list of commands with `sudo`.

Comment: You need to add * in commands. `%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt *,/usr/bin/apt-key *,/usr/bin/apt-add-repository *,/usr/bin/make *`

Comment: This gives an syntax error in the sudoers file, also as far as I understand all options, i.e. command line arguments for binaries should automatically be allowed when the binary is listed. I think you only need to specify command line arguments if you additionally want to restrict the executable to certain options.

Comment: visudo gives no errors(Ubuntu 18.04) but you are correct, * is not needed

Comment: This is so strange since I install a 19.10 and paste your line it just works...

Comment: For some reason, `env` is always being used to run the commands. I suspect an alias or shell function is at work. Can you **[edit]** this with a description of how `ubuntuuser` is executing the commands? If an interactive shell is being used, you could say what shell that is (`bash`?) and include complete text from the terminal, including the lines on which the commands are entered, including their prompts. If an interactive shell is not being used, then you could explain what is being done instead and also try it with one. Either way, from that shell, please show the output of `type -a sudo`.

Comment: This is the solution, to mitigate a command line problem regarding sudo and aliases I added this to my `.bash_aliases`: `alias sudo='sudo env "PATH=$PATH" '`. This was to help with some proprietary piece of software, that was not installed in the standard path. I changed it back to `alias sudo='sudo '` and now it works. I would gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As you found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188164/sudoers-file-allow-sudo-group-execution-of-only-certain-binaries#comment1986278_1188164), a shell alias made it so every command you ran with `sudo` ran the command through `env`, rather than directly.

After you edited `/etc/sudoers` to restrict what commands members of the `sudo` group could run, all `sudo` commands reported that you were not allowed to run `env`. So for some reason, every time you ran `sudo command`, it attempted to run the command with `env`. Furthermore, the error message always took this exact form:

```
Sorry, user ubuntuuser is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/env PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin command' as root on Ubuntumachine.
```

Using `env` in this way [is a common technique](https://askubuntu.com/a/1024004/22949) for making `sudo` use your `$PATH` rather than the value of its `secure_path` option. Some users define a shell alias or shell function called `sudo` to make `sudo command` run something like that. In Bash, running `type -a sudo` would show everything the `sudo` command might mean, with the meaning the shell chooses shown first. (`type sudo` would show just that one.)

[Having recalled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188164/sudoers-file-allow-sudo-group-execution-of-only-certain-binaries#comment1986278_1188164) the alias you defined, you were able to solve the problem by changing the alias not to use `env`. Removing the alias altogether would, of course, also work.

---

With that said, **I encourage you to consider *not* using this `sudoers` configuration**, because it has no security benefit compared to the default configuration. Actually it is somewhat less secure than the default configuration.

The main problem is that, while you appear to intend the line

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt,/usr/bin/apt-key,/usr/bin/apt-add-repository,/usr/bin/make
```

to constrain what commands members of the `sudo` group can run, **access to those commands is sufficient to perform any action whatsoever**. As an example of how this is so--and this is just one example--a member of the `sudo` group could create the following `Makefile`:

```make
.PHONY: elevate
elevate:
    su -
```

Then running `sudo make` gives a root shell with the same effect as successfully logging in as root. (Or `su -` could be replaced with another command, such as `visudo` to facilitate editing the `sudoers` file back. Or they could run `visudo` from the root shell given by `su -`.)

This cannot be solved by restricting what arguments are passed. In this case, `make` itself receives no command-line arguments.

The other commands you're allowing members of the `sudo` group to run are also sufficient to gain full access to the system. Even `apt` alone is enough to let users install whatever software they want, including software that is not from any configured repository (`apt install ./package.deb`). It is not hard to make one's own .deb package, and (among other lines of attack) .deb packages can include scripts that run as root at the time installation is performed.

**And then there is Polkit.** If this is a desktop system, Polkit in Ubuntu is configured to allow members of the `sudo` group to run arbitrary commands as root:

```
pkexec command
```

Even though it is configured by default to confer abilities to members of the `sudo` group, `pkexec` is unaffected by the contents of `sudoers` files.

This is less of a problem, at least in theory, in that you could reconfigure Polkit.

**The reason I say your configuration is *less* secure than the default** is that you are using `NOPASSWD`. This means that any program running as a member of the `sudo` group can perform any action whatsoever as root, without requiring any user interaction.

The security implications of `NOPASSWD`, though considerable, are sometimes overstated. After all, an attacker who gains control of a program run by a member of the `sudo` group can already put a fake `sudo` utility in place (for example, with the aid of an alias or shell function) and capture the user's password. That is likely to succeed. But it's a hassle, and it is not instant. `NOPASSWD` removes this hassle. You may decide you want to do that, but I recommend considering the risks carefully, especially if this is a multi-user system (which it sounds like it is).

---

From the commands you want to allow members of the `sudo` group to run, **it sounds like those users really do serve roles in administering the system**. That makes sense--after all, if they didn't, they would presumably not be members of the `sudo` group. Even within the "spirit" of your `sudoers` configuration, they can enable arbitrary repositories, install arbitrary software from them systemwide, and I presume letting them run `make` as root is so they can do the same with software they compile from source with commands like `sudo make install`.

If you fully trust the members of the `sudo` group (or perhaps it's just you) but just want to make it harder for them to do wrong things by accident, then one approach might be to give them separate accounts that are not in the `sudo` group, for tasks that don't require that they `sudo` to root.

If you don't trust them, then it is unlikely that there is a technical solution. Even if you were to lock down their abilities far more, it wouldn't be enough. The ability to control what software exists on the whole system, for use by all users, is always equivalent to the ability to perform arbitrary actions as root.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the really elaborate and enlightening answer. I am aware that the NOPASSWD makes the system less secure. I am not trying to lock out users from binaries but lock myself out from tampering with certain files. I try to keep an eye on my productivity and make it difficult to cheat, that is why I keep an elaborate `/etc/hosts` file that locks out most junk. By having a non memorable superuser password that I keep away while working and locking myself out from simply changing or moving the file with `sudo` privileges I can make it much harder and still do basic system maintenance.