# Executable running without sudo, but not with sudo

Tags: server, sudo

I have a program in a folder. I have changed its permission using `chmod u+x`. After that, its running without sudo on terminal, but when running with sudo, it shows `error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. 
The .so file exists on the directory its pointed, but it cannot find using sudo. I have followed the question [Executable runs without sudo but not with sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653029/executable-runs-without-sudo-but-not-with-sudo?noredirect=1&lq=1) but no luck. Please help. I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 Server

My /etc/sudoers file looks like this

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL


# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the so file ? Root may simply not have access to the file you are trying to run. I for example have this issue on my enterprise network with home drives where if you try to install something using sudo none of my users are able to as most cases it needs access to home directory where sudo/root doesn't have access.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"The .so file exists on the directory its pointed"*? Did you need to define a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in order to make the executable run without sudo?