# Where can I add to the ***universal*** path?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, paths

I'm a script kiddie of sorts and enjoy writing bash scripts for things, and I keep them in a repository that I synchronize, and on my personal computers I keep it in a home/otherStuff/customBin folder, but...

while I can add it to the .bashrc of every profile that gets tedious, and etc/environment doesn't seem to work for one reason or another.

(Edit) @steeldriver answered the below portion, but I still need the above question answered.

And the crux of the problem was, when I did "sudo customScript" it behaves like the file isn't on path, but doing "sudo -i" and then "customScript" does work just fine. How do I fix it?

"Under the default Ubuntu configuration, sudo uses its own secure_path in place of the environment's PATH - see for example Executable runs without sudo but not with sudo" –
steeldriver

Comment: Under the default Ubuntu configuration, `sudo` uses its own `secure_path` in place of the environment's `PATH` - see for example [Executable runs without sudo but not with sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653029/executable-runs-without-sudo-but-not-with-sudo)

Comment: @steeldriver, That answers the crux of the problem I'm having, but not quite the full question I posed it in. I'll edit the question to include such.

Comment: If you run `sudo -l` you will likely see that `secure_path` contains both `/usr/local/sbin` and `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Still answering the crux of the problem driving the question, but still not the question. How do I add something to the systemwide path? Is there any way other than /etc/environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executable runs without sudo but not with sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653029/executable-runs-without-sudo-but-not-with-sudo)

Comment: @ArturMeinild, its Still answering the crux of the problem driving the question, but still not the question. Someone did answer the question though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make it a universal path by adding to the `/etc/profile` file and also make it add a check.

If you add the following to the bottom of the `/etc/profile` then when you reboot it should be able to add it to the path universally or globally:

```
# Check for script directory and add to path
if [ -e /home/otherStuff/customBin ]; then
    PATH=/home/otherStuff/customBin:$PATH
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual place to put user installed applications (and scripts) is `/usr/local/bin`.

You only need `sudo` to copy/sync the scripts to this location.

`/usr/local/bin` should be in your path, and if executable, scripts can be run by all users.

Comment: This is good advice, but because I want to sync just my scripts with bin and don't want to worry about lingering old scripts if I delete one, or trying to .gitignore everything other than my stuff in that folder, because too many other programs already use that folder.

Comment: @Terrance sure - fixed typo.