# How can I use ZSH when I use sudo commands but not as default root shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, zsh

So, I would like to keep `bash` as the default shell for root.

But, I would prefer to use `zsh`, my shell, when I run `sudo` commands, and that `sudo` executes also the .zshrc in /root.

For testing purposes, I have created an alias in my `/root/.zshrc` and `~/.zshrc` :

```
alias test1='echo "Test OK"'
```

Now, when I run `sudo su` <kbd>enter</kbd> `zsh` <kbd>enter</kbd> `test1` <kbd>enter</kbd>

I got the expected result : `Test OK`

However, all of these commands result in : `test1: command not found`

```
sudo test1
sudo su -c 'zsh -c test1'
sudo -E zsh -c 'test1'
sudo ZDOTDIR=/root/.zshrc test1
sudo ZDOTDIR=/root/.zshrc zsh -c 'test1'
sudo ZDOTDIR=/root/.zshrc zsh -c 'source /root/.zshrc && test1'
```

I found [this question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo), but I think this is more related to [this one on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131716/start-zsh-with-a-custom-zshrc).

However, none of these posts help me.

What I want to achieve in final is to create a simple alias that could replace `sudo` when I want to use `zsh` with its /root/.zshrc file, and prefix the command I want to run.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a zsh user, but `sudo zsh -c test1` is failing because the shell has not read your .zshrc file. Try this:

```
sudo zsh -ic test1
```

That should tell zsh that this is in interactive shell, so source the .zshrc file.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But, how can I write my alias command to prevent quoting my commands ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: See the last paragraph of my question. I want to write an alias (say `sudozsh` and use it in the same way of `sudo`). `alias sudozsh='sudo zsh -ic'` doesn't work with commands such as `tail -f /var/log/syslog`.  I would like also not having to backslash quotes in commands.

Comment: You'll have to handle shell control operators like `&&` specially, so use your alias, but quote the command to send: `sudozsh 'tail -f'`, `sudozsh 'cd /remote/dir && tar cf - .' | tar xf -`