# Unable to login into Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, login-screen, paths, vmware-player

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (On VM Player) but unable to login suddenly. I am entering the correct password, because if I enter wrong password it gives password error message, and not otherwise.
It just stays on the login screen - no error nothing. I have restarted VM Player and VM a few times, etc

Adding more details
My orginal issue was my program not finding JAVA_HOME even though it is there.

**1.** Originally I had setup PATH  in etc/environemnt.

```
$ sudo service dse start
**Java executable not found (hint: set JAVA_HOME)**
@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/jdk1.8.0_111
@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Java exists as above

**2.** Then I setup PATH .bashrc (this also did not work)
export JAVA_HOME= /opt/jdk1.8.0_111
export PATH= $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

3. Added path to .profile (same as above) now removed from .bashrc and etc/environemnt
   **After this my login issues have started.**

The original hypothesis was there maybe multiple java versions causing conflicts but that may not be true:

```
~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
```

Thx

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48977/discussion-on-question-by-sam-t-unable-to-login-into-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Remove path variable from /etc/environment, .bashrc and .profile.

Now add following line only in /etc/environment as,
  `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin‌:/usr/games:/usr/loc‌​al/games:/opt/jdk1.8‌​.0_111/bin"`

Undo whatever you added in .bashrc and .profile file.

Comment: The the login issue was solved by recovering .profile (I had some typo in it). But the original JAVA_HOME issue remains (??!!)

Comment: Did you use the same path variable as I have provided in answer?? If not post your path variable.

Answer (score 0):

This login issue was resolved (thanks to many) by recovering the .profile by `/bin/cp /etc/skel/.profile .`  And fixing the typo in it (had a missing quote in PATH).

Comment: The `skel` version of `.profile` did not have a typo in it, so could you clarify what you mean by that,

Answer (score 0):

For PATH problem for running my command I did:

```
sudo env PATH="$PATH" service dse start
```

[Environment variables when run with 'sudo'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo)