# `sudo` is not using the right binary, even when $PATH is correctly passed

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, pipenv

I am trying to run a Pipenv python instance as root. When not run as root:

```
(myenv) $ python script.py
```

the Pipenv python is correctly used. However, when run as root with `sudo`:

```
(myenv) $ sudo python script.py
```

the system default python at `/usr/bin/python` is used instead. After some searching, I found the `-E` option for sudo. However, with

```
(myenv) $ sudo -E python script.py
```

it still uses `/usr/bin/python`, even though `sudo -E echo $PATH` gives the same as `echo $PATH`, so the `-E` option works fine; however, `sudo -E which python` continues to give `/usr/bin/python`! It is not a permissions or access problem because the full path to the Pipenv python works fine. Why is the wrong binary being used even though `$PATH` is set correctly?

Comment: `sudo` won't use your pyenv environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's the problem. When I was troubleshooting, I wanted to find the value of $PATH inside sudo. However, with `sudo -E echo $PATH`, my user (non-sudo) shell was expanding it automatically, so sudo just saw

```
echo /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/environment-_Sko9eTd/bin:/usr/bin/:......
```

Trying `sudo -E env` tells us the real story:

```
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
# more environment variables ...
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
# ^^ doesn't include my Pipenv path
```

so in fact, `sudo -E` was not passing `$PATH`. To fix this you can then see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/713137) on a similar question. Essentially you just add

```
Defaults env_reset
Defaults env_keep += "PATH PYTHONPATH"
```

to your sudoers file with `visudo`.